# In which release did Java Data Objects (JDO) first start allowing annotations as an alternative to XML?

Tags: java, annotations, jdo

My understanding is that the original incarnation of JDO required the use of XML files to describe the metadata but I see that the most recent version allows annotations.

Is this correct?

If so, when did annotations first become available in JDO as an alternative to XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [apaches JDO](http://db.apache.org/jdo/) page:

> The JDO 2.1 maintenance release provides support for JDK 1.5 features,including the use of annotations as a means of specifying mapping.

Most recent release is JDO 2.2, for 2.3 there's an early access release (again, this information is valid for apache JDO).

Comment: 2.3 is virtually finished FWIW